# How to automatically select solutions from a set of solutions given by Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, filtering

I have a function of trigonometric functions which must be equated to zero in order to obtain the appropriate results. This is done in the following fashion:

```
Solve[G[a,b,y,x]==0,x},
```

which returns several results, all of which only one has significance to me. I know I can select this result by using, for example,

```
Solve[G[a,b,y,x]==0,x}[[1]][[2]]
```

but I need to plot such results, so I used the Solve command in a Table command

```
data = Table[{y,Solve[G[a,b,y,x]==0, {x, -90, 90}];
```

The problem is that this gives me, sometimes 4 results sometimes 2, but I'm always interested in the smallest real result. How can I select automatically only the result that interests me?

Here is the function I'm using:

```
G[ni_, ki_, nt_, kt_, y_, x_] := 

Sqrt[(ni^2 - ki^2) + Sqrt[((ni^2 - ki^2)^2 + 
4 ((ni ki)/Cos[y])^2)]] Sin[y] - 

  Sqrt[(nt^2 - kt^2) + 
    Sqrt[((nt^2 - kt^2)^2 + 4 ((nt kt)/Cos[x])^2)]]Sin[x]
```

and parameters:

```
data = Table[{y,Solve[G[1.391, 1.19, 2.6, 1.3, y Pi/180, x Pi/180] == 0, x]}, {y, -90, 90}];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: First thing to try would be the Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: The code contains obvious errors: `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.` and `Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients`. You must take either rational factors, or use `NSolve[]`. And eliminate the division by 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a solution for the minimum real root

```
G[ni_, ki_, nt_, kt_, y_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[(ni^2 - ki^2) + 
     Sqrt[((ni^2 - ki^2)^2 + 4 ((ni ki)/Cos[y])^2)]] Sin[y] - 
  Sqrt[(nt^2 - kt^2) + 
     Sqrt[((nt^2 - kt^2)^2 + 4 ((nt kt)/Cos[x])^2)]] Sin[x]
 Table[{y, 
  x /. (First[
      NSolve[G[1391/1000, 119/100, 26/10, 13/10, y Pi/180, 
         x Pi/180] == 0, x, Reals]] /. C[1] -> 0)}, {y, -80, 80, 10}]

Out[]= {{-80, -66.3258}, {-70, -47.9345}, {-60, -36.8608}, {-50, \
-28.9019}, {-40, -22.3127}, {-30, -16.3845}, {-20, -10.7898}, {-10, \
-5.36059}, {0, 0.}, {10, 5.36059}, {20, 10.7898}, {30, 16.3845}, {40, 
  22.3127}, {50, 28.9019}, {60, 36.8608}, {70, 47.9345}, {80, 
  66.3258}}
ListPlot[%]
```

[image: fig1]